# departure stamp was not affixed at Haridaspur immigration

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, bangladeshi-citizens

On December 16, 2022, I passed Bangladesh immigration (Benapole) and got a departure stamp on my passport. I also got an arrival stamp on my passport at the Indian immigration (Haridaspur) desk.
On December 17, 2022, I passed the Indian immigration (Haridaspur) desk but inadvertently departure stamp was not affixed by the counter officer on my passport. After crossing Indian immigration, I reached Bangladesh immigration (Benapole) and got my arrival stamp from the Bangladesh immigration (Benapole) authority.
Later, when I discovered that the departure stamp from the Indian immigration (Haridaspur) desk was missing on my passport, I immediately reached for the Indian immigration (Haridaspur) desk in pursuit of correction of departure formalities, but they did not correct that but they stamped my passport with "Entry Refugee-Immigration Reason.".
What can i do now to travel India again ?

Comment: Do you mean "Entry Refused"?  Can you attach a photo of the stamp, and what did they tell you when they stamped that?

Comment: Also, can you confirm your nationality (Bangladeshi, I presume?) and what kind of visa you hold for India?